# Is possible to loop a readUTF to read multiple unknown server lines?

Tags: java, stream, client-server

I'm wondering if there is a way to loop a .readUTF from a code like this:

```
public void startClient() throws IOException {
   DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        System.out.println(input.readUTF()); 
        System.out.println(input.readUTF());

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name= scanner.nextLine();        
        DataOutputStream output= new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        output.writeUTF(name);
        ....
```

In this case I know server is going to send two messages so I wrote two input.readUTF() BUT how could I do this if I didn't know the amount of messages?

Thank you

Comment: Hi @Weenhallo - how do you know when it isn't sending UTF8?  So it sends 3 - a) how do you know? then b) how do you know it stops?

Comment: It's an exercise, so I'm practising the server part and client part so I know there is two inputs because I wrote two outputs on the server part. I don't know if that is what are you asking me... I'm very new with client/server things. (I'll update with server code too if you need it)

Comment: Hi @Weenhallo - you'll get an EOFExecption if you read and there's nothing to read... I'm asking how will your code know to stop processing UTF8 or do you just want to read till the stream exhausted - i.e. you can use a `while` ... the JavaDoc explains exactly how it works - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html#readUTF()

Comment: So I should put all my code on a try catch with an EOFException right? But It doesn't clarify me if there is a way to loop the input. Or maybe I'm just slow learning hahah

Comment: @user1535884 _only would be when connection closed_ that was what I was effectively trying to say, however we only see the code the given, and clearly there's some reading to be done / protocol issues to be thought about, etc.

Comment: @Weenhallo the javadoc suggests that you'll get everything in 1 go - but maybe that's not the case when a read returns zero bytes (in the case of a socket stream).. to loop it do `while (!finished) { readUTF.. }` - will keep reading until the finished condition is true.  You have to worked out how finished (which was what my first question was - is there a protocol saying finished [bye message], or something else (EOFException)) and that is the terminator of the while...   But it may sit there waiting for ever .. perhaps you want to deal with that case too (a timeout ...)